# Using ActiveMQ 5.11.1 with JBoss 7.4.3 (EAP 6.3.3)

Tags: jboss7.x, activemq-classic

I try to run an embedded ActiveMQ with Jboss 7.4.3 by following the installation tips I find on several sites like:

- https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/EmbedActiveMQInJBossAS7
- https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss6EAPOr7xxToApacheActiveMQ56Or7

In general I put activemq-rar-5.11.1.rar in standalone/deployments and add a resource-adapter config entry in the standalone.xml.

In the extensions section I added 

and in the entry 
i added

```
<mdb>
  <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="activemq-rar-5.11.1.rar" />
  <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool" />
</mdb>
```

to make ActiveMQ the default JMS provider.

I get no errors on startup, but in the logfile I see nothing else than

```
JBAS018559: "activemq-rar-5.11.1.rar" deployed (runtime-name: "activemq-rar-5.11.1.rar")
```

I see nothing in the jndi bindings and trying to access the connectionFactory

```
    @Resource(mappedName = "java:jboss/activemq/QueueConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

results in this error:

```
service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.activemq.QueueConnectionFactory (fehlende) Dependents: ...
```

Have I missed anything?

Comment: As I understood the documentation the embedded broker should been started automatically it I configure the URL to vm:localhost Is this correct or do I have to do more? I modifed the URL in the resource adapter config (standalone.xml) and in the ra.xml in the exploded rar archive.

Comment: Update: There is a bug in EAP 6.3 regarding this: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1116788 - Has anybody experience in starting an embedded message broker via CLI?